# Why numpy array is faster than list in python?

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have recently discovered that numpy array is faster than normal list in python.I have run the code below

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import pandas as pd

my_listy = list(range(1000000))

my_array = np.array(range(1000000))

%time for i in range(10): my_list2 = my_listy * 2

%time for i in range(10): my_array2 = my_array * 2
```

I found that execution time for the list was approx 425 ms  whereas the execution time for the numpy array was approx 371 ms. Whats the specific reason for this ??

Comment: you compare unrelated things. `[1,2,3] * 2 = [1,2,3,1,2,3]`, while `np.array([1,2,3]) * 2 = np.array([2,4,6])`

Comment: You do completely different things: `my_listy * 2` is the original list repeated twice, while `my_array2 = my_array * 2` multiplies each of the original values by 2.

Comment: @Learner909, it's not appropriate to edit a question *in a way that invalidates answers that have already been added*. If you asked the wrong question by mistake, you can fix that when there aren't yet correct answers present -- but after it's answered, the remedy is to ask a new and different question.

Comment: (When doing that, be sure you call out _why_ that question is different so it doesn't get mistakenly closed as a duplicate: "Similar question X asked about this-thing; whereas this question asks about that-thing").

Comment: @Learner909, ...that said, I don't see why anyone would expect numpy arrays _not_ to be faster: They're _arrays_, not linked lists. Allocating an array of a given size is an O(1) operation, a single malloc call. Appending to a linked list means allocating a new cell; appending to an array that was already allocated to be large enough is just a direct write to the destination of a pointer. Arrays are _always_ faster than linked lists for these specific operations, in _any_ language. (On the other hand, they're slower for others; you can't easily insert in the middle of an array).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, but Python lists are not linked lists.

Comment: It's like the whole reason for numpy arrays to exist

Answer (score 2):

You are performing two completely different operations here so you cannot directly compare: multiplying a list by 2 will create a new list where the list is concatenated to itself (so the length of the output list is twice that of the input list), whereas multiplying a numpy array by 2 will create a new array of the same length as the original array, but in which each element has been multiplied by 2.

Nonetheless, if you had attempted to perform a list operation which actually corresponds to the numpy case (element-by-element multiplication), for example:

```
my_list2 = [n * 2 for n in my_listy]
```

you would also have found that the numpy example was quicker.  This is because the required looping in numpy is performed in a shared library consisting of compiled C code, rather than using an explicit loop in Python (`for` loop or list comprehension).

```
$ python -mtimeit -s 'import numpy as np; my_array = np.array(range(1000000))' 'my_array2 = my_array * 2'
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.45 msec per loop

$ python -mtimeit -s 'my_listy = list(range(1000000))' 'my_list2 = [n*2 for n in my_listy]'
10 loops, best of 3: 50.8 msec per loop
```

Comment: if you replace `my_array2 = my_array * 2` with `my_array *=2` the performance would increase about twice

Comment: @tstanisl Believably so, but an in-place modification is not really a like-for-like comparison.

Answer (score 0):

> The following are the main reasons behind the fast speed of Numpy.
> -Numpy array is a collection of similar data-types that are densely packed in memory. A Python list can have different data-types, which puts lots of extra constraints while doing computation on it.
> -Numpy is able to divide a task into multiple subtasks and process them parallelly.
> -Numpy functions are implemented in C. Which again makes it faster compared to Python Lists.

Python at first was not made for numeric operations but with time numpy was created for this scope(making python better at numeric operations).
Source: [towardsdatascience.com](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-fast-numpy-really-is-e9111df44347#:%7E:text=As%20the%20array%20size%20increase,also%20frees%20the%20memory%20faster.)

Comment: This is all true on its own, but it doesn't go into the details of the OP's code. (Also, CPython lists are implemented in C just as much as numpy arrays are).

Answer (score 0):

NumPy outperforms Python lists due to its inherent advantages, including homogeneous data types and the efficient storage of arrays in contiguous memory blocks, enabling it to execute operations more swiftly and with superior memory management.

The code clearly demonstrates the superior speed of NumPy over Python lists, showcasing NumPy's efficiency in handling large datasets and performing complex mathematical operations with remarkable speed and precision.:

```
import numpy as np
import time


start_time = time.time()
numpy_array = np.arange(1_000_000)
result = numpy_array.sum()
numpy_execution_time = time.time() - start_time


start_time = time.time()
python_list = list(range(1_000_000))
result = sum(python_list)
python_execution_time = time.time() - start_time

print("NumPy execution time:", numpy_execution_time)
print("Python list execution time:", python_execution_time)
```

Answer (score -1):

In Numpy You have implementation in C++, that this is faster than pure python.

Comment: CPython is itself implemented in C. Yes, numpy is faster, but implementation language isn't really why (as opposed to decisions about what level of operations to implement in that low-level language, when comparing like-against-like). Here, though, the OP isn't even comparing like against like: Their numpy code and their Python code do completely different things.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I think any like-against-like comparison is going to involve explicit loops in Python in one form or another when using lists, hence be a lot slower - see my example timings with list comprehension (factor of 35).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Granted, the `my_list * 2` is implemented in C, but this isn't much help if it doesn't actually do the required operation.